# Haskell How to return a list of int from two int list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

if `list1 = [14,24,1,2,11,7,23,8,12,22,20,0,15,19,4,9,10,21,18,17,3,13,16,5,6,25]`,
and `list2 = [14,14,24,24,1,1,2,2]`
How could I return a int list which is `[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]`

I have used the function

```
elemIndex' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
elemIndex' x = fromMaybe (-1) . elemIndex x
```

and the result for this for the first one
`0`
to get the index from list 1 for a single digit
But what I want is

```
findIndex :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

That would input two int list and return the index value base on the key list
How could I recursively get the index for one list or using any import function, such as map.

Comment: Please don't use tags that are irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You've done a very good job of breaking the problem down. You've already recognized that you're doing the same thing for *each* element of the second list, and you've written a function to capture that behavior.

```
elemIndex' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
elemIndex' x = fromMaybe (-1) . elemIndex x
```

Now you want to take this function and apply it to *each* element of another list, collecting the results into a new list. That is, you want something that looks like

```
mystery :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

And we can search [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) and find exactly that function: [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

`map` takes a function and a list and applies it to each element. You've got a function (`elemIndex'`, with appropriate partial application), and you've got a list (`list2` in your example). So let's put it together.

```
findAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Int]
findAll haystack needles = map (\x -> elemIndex' x haystack) needles
```

There are lots of streaming functions in Haskell like `map`, and knowing / figuring out which one to use in a given situation comes with practice. If you're ever in doubt, remember that you can use Hoogle to search for a type or you can simply do whatever you're trying to do recursively (if you didn't know `map` existed, you could write it yourself with a bit of recursion), and you'll get the hang of it over time. Good luck in your Haskell endeavors!

Comment: Thank you so much. For the \x is this the anonymous function, and we define it by using lambda?

Comment: Yep, `\x -> ...` is an anonymous function. The backslash was chosen because it's the thing on your keyboard that most closely resembles the Greek lambda `λ`

Comment: `\x -> elemIndex' x haystack` could also be replaced with ```(`elemIndex'` haystack)```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer by @SilvioMayolo, you could use a `Map` data structure. We `zip` in the indexes for each value in `list1` and then turn that into a map, then just do a lookup for each value in `list2`.

```hs
import Data.Map
import Data.List

list1 = [14,24,1,2,11,7,23,8,12,22,20,0,15,19,4,9,10,21,18,17,3,13,16,5,6,25]
list2 = [14,14,24,24,1,1,2,2]

map1 = Data.Map.fromList $ list1 `zip` [0..]
-- fromList [(0,11),(1,2),(2,3),(3,20),(4,14),(5,23),(6,24),
--           (7,5),(8,7),(9,15),(10,16),(11,4),(12,8),(13,21),
--           (14,0),(15,12),(16,22),(17,19),(18,18),(19,13),
--           (20,10),(21,17),(22,9),(23,6),(24,1),(25,25)]

list3 = Data.List.map (map1 !) list2
-- [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]
```